# Fourier transformation on $L^2(G)$.

Tags: fourier-analysis, definition, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

We define Fourier transform on $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and extend the definition to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
But for a compact group $G$, we define Fourier transform for $L^2(G)$ and there is no such thing of defining for $L^1(G)$.

My question is why such unusual thing happens for groups? Is this because $L^2(G)$ is Hilbert space? I want an answer from very deep point.

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is a compact group and $\mu$ is the left-invariant Haar measure on $G$, then $\mu(G)$ is finite, so $L^2(G)\subset L^1(G)$ by Holder's inequality and we can directly define the Fourier transform on $L^2(G)$ since all the integrals in question are defined.

However $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is not a subset of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, which is why it is necessary to extend the Fourier transform to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ using some dense subset.

Comment: So is it that we need Fourier transform on L2 in long run and we don't care for L1?

Comment: You can define the Fourier transform on $L^1$, but the $L^2$ theory is what works out so nicely.